# scp to AWS EC2 permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cmd, server, scp

I am very new to AWS ec2, using linux, and using scp commands, just to get that out of the way. I have an AWS ec2 instance set up and want to upload a python file to that instance using an scp server command. The command I am using is scp -i `C:\Users\Mason Choi\django_market_predict\Anchor_training_key_pair.pem C:\Users\Mason Choi\django_market_predict\mysite\train.py ec2-user@ec2-54-83-108-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user`

The error message I get when trying to use this command in my terminal (windows cmd) is

```
arning: Identity file C:/Users/Mason not accessible: No such file or directory.
ec2-user@ec2-54-83-108-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
lost connection
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction? I have referenced many sources telling me to add certain permissions, which I have followed, and I do suspect the issue to either be with permissions or ssh key something. Thanks!

Below is the full error log

```
    Warning: Identity file C:/Users/Mason not accessible: No such file or directory.
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "ec2-54-83-108-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-83-108-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com [54.83.108.233] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_rsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_ed25519 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-54-83-108-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-54-83-108-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:5Pdzz6YRuysub6ZzFsYvFdFQDhVn5ecEuzSL4tBmVKs
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-54-83-108-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 54.83.108.233
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Mason Choi/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host 'ec2-54-83-108-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Mason Choi/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ubuntu@ec2-54-83-108-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately you're getting caught up in a directory name that has a space character in it.  As you can see:

> Warning: Identity file C:/Users/Mason not accessible: No such file or directory.

Note that the command is broken where your name has a space in it.  To overcome this run:

```
scp -i "C:\Users\Mason Choi\django_market_predict\Anchor_training_key_pair.pem" "C:\Users\Mason Choi\django_market_predict\mysite\train.py" ec2-user@ec2-54-83-108-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user
```

Answer (score 1):

I have marked the correct answer above-but I wanted to share a solution that I used instead. I used a program called FireZilla and it is the absolute best/ easiest way to upload your files to AWS EC2. You literally can drag and drop your files from your computer and create new directories without any commands whatsoever, I highly recommend it. Please follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUHQuZjTOFA) to use, and also that you to @stdunbar for his answer as well.